# Cardinality of a conjugacy class

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non abelian group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $p$ divides $q-1$.

I've shown that :

1. There is a unique subgroup of order $q$ in $G$ : it's the derived subgroup.
2. The center is trivial.
3. There are $q$ subgroups of order $p$, and they are conjugate to each other.
4. Every element of order $p$ has exactly $q$ conjugates.

Now I'm asked to show that an element of order $q$ has exactly $p$ conjugates... And I need help, please :)

Comment: This follows from the fact that its centralizer has order $q$, since otherwise the centralizer would have order $pq$ and it would lie in the centre, which you have already proved to be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So let $a$ be an element of order $q$, its centralizer has order $q$, namely its centralizer is $\lbrace 1, \dots, a^{q-1}\rbrace$. But how does this help ?

Comment: The number of conjugates of an element $g \in G$ is equal to the index of its centralizer i.e. size of conjugacy class = $|G|/C_G(g)|$.

Comment: Oh ok sure !! I didn't think about linking this to a group action. Thank you very much !!